# problem restarting apache2

Tags: installation, apache2

When trying to restart apache2,

I type:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Response I get:

```
Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In the main configuration file, make sure the ServerName has a proper value.

`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Find or add the following

`ServerName localhost`

You can use any FQDN instead of localhost.