# Running into trouble restarting Apache 2

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php

I am attempting to restart Apache and am getting the following message...

> ```
> > devil@DEVil:/etc/apache2$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart  *
> > Restarting web server apache2                                         
> > AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully
> > qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive
> > globally to suppress this message
> ```

The solution to this problem seems to be to enter `ServerName localhost` into the `apache2.conf` file ([problem restarting apache2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309278/problem-restarting-apache2)).

When I go into this file try to alter it it won't let me save as `apache2.conf` is a "read only" file. How can I alter the permissions to make it writable so I can get Apache up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit the file as the root user, which could be achieved by entering the command `sudo` in front of the command you're using to edit the file (and entering the password for your user if asked for one).

For example if you're using vim the command should be

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and you could replace `vim` with `mc`, `nano`, `pico` or whatever you prefer

Comment: Thanks! I figured this out literally 2 seconds before you posted the answer. I used "gksu gedit".

Comment: Keep in mind that Apache is used mostly on installations without any graphical environment and gksudo and gedit might not always be available.